# Salesforce app license conversion

Tags: salesforce

We have a Salesforce application which is being listed at **Appexchange**, and we are providing trial of 45 days, many of the clients are using the application and for some trial period has been finished but they want to continue, so they can become the active user of our app.
For developer perspective, we are managing **LMO** at our organization and we can see the license has been expired for their org. Many documentation of Salesforce says that, we can change the License type from trial to active, but was not able to do even when we logged through License Manager credentials.

**So In short I want help at two points.**

- If we want to extend license for particular org, How can we do that
  from LMO?
- How can a customer himself expect to convert his license    from
  trial to active, without loosing the application data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the page layout, you will see Modify License button, drag it to custom button field area, utilize it to change the license.